# unable to play video of react-native-video

Tags: react-native

Hello guys I am stuck while executing [this code.](https://github.com/browniefed/examples/tree/rnvideo/controls)
I have done everything all right but I am getting this error.

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOiIp.png)

I have even tried linking 'react-native link react-native-video' also but it is not fixing my problem. I tries almost all solutions i found while googling my error.

can someone please help me solving this problem . I will be very glad if some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

This code is 3 years old. It is too old to execute the new RN and new libraries.

I suggest you create a new project with `react-native init NewProject` command and try the react-native-video with a new project. If it works which works very well actually :) You can migrate this code to the new project. After you install the react-native-video, you need to `pod install` before running the project.

Answer (score 0):

i have used pods like this

`pod 'react-native-video', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-video'`

after adding the pods try to link react-native-video manually.

Hope this works for you.